# Android Wear простой пример обмена данными со смартфоном

Tags: android, android-wear

Собственно, вопрос в названии... Не смог найти простейшего примера обмена данными между смартфоном и часами... 
Прошу именно простейший пример, исходники семплов, что идут вместе с SDK избыточно большие и сложные.

Comment: >исходники семплов, что идут вместе с SDK избыточно большие и сложные.

В таком случае подтягивайте матчасть и возвращайтесь к примерам как подтянете.

Comment: @Deadkenny, с матчастью все в порядке. Если не можете посоветовать что-то полезное, не стоит напрягать пальцы для печати вообще

Comment: @metalurgus, если найдется решение, запостите, пожалуйста, сам мучаюсь.
____
@metalurgus, подправил ответ, свою задачу таким путем решил.

Comment: Так же есть хорошо описанный пример работы с DataAPI: http://android-wear-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/data.html
И готовый по нему проект: https://github.com/LarkspurCA/WearableDataMap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите [тут](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html) и [тут](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html).

**#1 Отправка сообщения из активити на часах**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        initApi();
    }

//Конектимся к API
private void initApi() {
        client = getGoogleApiClient(this);
        retrieveDeviceNode();
        client.connect();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a GoogleApiClient that can access the Wear API.
     *
     * @param context
     * @return A GoogleApiClient that can make calls to the Wear API
     */
    private GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient(Context context) {
        return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the GoogleApiClient and retrieves the connected device's Node ID. If there are
     * multiple connected devices, the first Node ID is returned.
     */
    private void retrieveDeviceNode() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                client.blockingConnect(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult result =
                        Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(client).await();
                List<Node> nodes = result.getNodes();
                if (nodes.size() > 0) {
                    nodeId = nodes.get(0).getId();
                }
                client.disconnect();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    /**
     * Отправляем "сообщение" к подключенному телефону, передаем параметр yourData                        (какие то ваши данные), или null вместо него.
     */
    private void sendMessageToMobile() {
        if (nodeId != null) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    client.blockingConnect(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(client, nodeId, MESSAGE, new byte[]{yourData});
                    client.disconnect();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
```

**#2 Принимаем "сообщение" на телефоне**

```
public class ListenerService  extends WearableListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

   //Ваши действия

}
```

**В манифесте:**

```
 <service android:name=".ListenerService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

А так же в манифесте wear модуля нужно добавить гугл плей сервис